# Json feed into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Im having some issues when trying to get some Json data into a specific format.

I basically need this Json data:

```
{
query: [ ],
products:  [
 {
title: "title 1",
price: "6.00",
magazine: "magazine name 1",
image: "/p/c/pc_90_cover.jpg",
type: "Magazine",
market: "Technology",
zinio: "http:www.zinio.com",
newsstand: "http://www.link1.php"
},

 {
title: "title 2",
price: "6.00",
magazine: "magazine name 2",
image: "/p/c/pc_90_cover.jpg",
type: "Magazine",
market: "Technology",
zinio: "http:www.zinio.com",
newsstand: "http://www.link2.php"
},

 {
title: "title 3",
price: "6.00",
magazine: "magazine name 3",
image: "/p/c/pc_90_cover.jpg",
type: "Magazine",
market: "Technology",
zinio: "http:www.zinio.com",
newsstand: "http://www.link3.php"
}
]
```

To go into this javascript array:

```
var arrProducts = [
                          title:  "{{ product.title }}",
                          url:  "{{ product.url }}",
                          label:  "{{ product.title }}",
                          magazine: "{{ product.magazine }}",
                          image: "{{ product.imageThumb }}",
                          newsstand: "{{ product.newsstand }}",
                          kindle: "{{ product.kindle }}",
                          barnesnoble: "{{ product.barnesnoble }}",
                          zinio: "{{ product.zinio }}",
                          kobo: "{{ product.kobo }}",
                          waterstones: "{{ product.waterstones }}",
                          type: "{{ product.type }}",
                      },
             ];
```

I have tried using:

```
var allProducts = $.get("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json, function(data) {

var productsArray = data.products; 

console.log(productsArray);

});
```

But that method does not build the array in the format I require. Console.log outputs a bunch of objects. Maybe an for each loop could be a solution? - Any help is appreciated, my Javascript isnt that great!

Comment: Your desired result has syntax errors. Do you need an array of hashmaps?

Comment: You need to parse the resulting data to convert it.  The first line of the success function should be `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Tried adding that in but I got the following error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o :8888/great-digital-mags/web/app.php/:168
(anonymous function) :8888/great-digital-mags/web/app.php/:168
o jquery.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://jsonlint.com to validate your json. If it won't pass there, it won't pass through ajax either. Your sample is missing double quotes on object keys and a starting  brace and has extra comma and your file shoudn't include `var arrProducts =` when consumed by ajax

There is a difference however if you place a script tag with this file in page during initial page load. Then the `var arrProducts =` is needed and the quotes on object keys are not. Then rather than ajax you would simply loop over the variable `arrProducts`

**EDit:**

To loop over first sample

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data) { 
    var productsArray = data.products;  
    $.each(  productsArray, function( i, item){ 

         console.log( 'Title is '+ item.title)

    })

})
```

There is a wealth of information available about how to parse json and loop over objects and arrays ... did you try searching?

Comment: The Json included in the example I gave did have errors but the Json im working with does validate correctly.  It was just copied over incorrectly in the example I gave...opps! So how exactly would I loop over arrproducts to build an array to match the one in my example?

Comment: This solution does work but I am still left with the original issue  of the data being an object.  How do I transform this into a string array?

Comment: format of second sample is an array of objects so not entirely sure what you are needing

Comment: I think  I know.. you want to merge data from 2 sources ? Is this correct?